# Incorporate an Excel workbook in a VSTO Excel Add-In

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, vba

Am rewriting an Excel VBA Add-In as a VSTO Excel Add-In (and switching to C#).
In the VBA version I have worksheets available to store formulas etc., and generally manipulate the data (which will have been copied in from the active worksheet when the add-in was invoked).
With VSTO there is no equivalent .xlam workbook with worksheets to store such formulas.
So I'm trying to figure out how to store/access such a "helper" workbook.  I do realize I could build the formulas in code, but storing them in spreadsheet(s) makes it much more maintainable.
I've tried embedding such a workbook but am struggling to access it and then use it like I could in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

In traditional VBA code, your code is part of a workbook and hence you could use to "store" some config. In an add-in, there is no such thing. It is application level and hence no specific document is available.

a) You could store the formulas as XML or something and do what you want with them

b) It seems like what you want is not an add-in, but a document level customization. If you do that, your "code" is attached to a particular document. There you could potentially use a "template" worksheet or even customize the sheets, look and feel, formulas, add ranges, whatever you need.